# Visual Studio code always opens the wrong file for me

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a very weird problem with Visual studio code (Version 1.20.1 (1.20.1)).

In full screen mode on a Mac. (High Sierra) when I double click a file. it always opens the file above it. Meaning that it opens the wrong file (not the one which I double clicked).

Please have a look at this video which I recorded.

https://youtu.be/VG8-AnEpZjY

The video starts with me double click on the file "Tables.scala" but the editor opens the file "ScanFromCassandra" which is above it.

Then I double click Models.scala and it opens the file correctly.

Then I double click Config.scala but the editor opens CommonFlow.scala

This is very very annoying. I don't know if anyone else is facing this issue or not.

Edit:: If I switch off the "open editors" window, then the issue disappears. but I like the "open editors" window. I think the open editors window causes some kind of "jumping" in vscode making it open wrong files.

Comment: yes it opens both files.

Comment: Are you are using a wireless mouse with touch controls and if so did you just start using it? The reason I ask is that I started using a new mac with the wireless mouse and I had a similar experience where I had to train myself to be very careful about exactly how I used the mouse lest the touch controls would make me click on items usually above the item I wanted. though the opening of both files in your case makes me think maybe your issue is different.

Comment: I am using the standard trackpad of MBP. and the problem disappears in the "open editors" window is shut. So this is not a hardware issue.

Comment: which vscode version are you using?

Comment: Version 1.20.1 (1.20.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured out the answer after using the editor for some time.

in VSCode when trying to open files in the "explorer" we have to single click on the file name. not double click.

If I single click on the file name it works perfectly.

The problem comes when I double click but that's not required. a single click on the file name to open it works smoothly.